# python unable to import module

Tags: python, import, package

I have my program set up using packages as followed:

```
-base
    -init.py
    -base_class.py
-test
    -init.py
    -test.py
```

When I do the import statement `from base.base_class import BaseClass` in the `test.py` I get this error when running it:

```
from base.base_class import BaseClass
ImportError: No module named base.base_class
```

How can I import this module?

Comment: Made an edit, added init.py but the problem is still there

Answer (score 7):

at the top of test.py add

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

base is not a folder on the path...once you change this it should work

or put test.py in the same folder as base.  or move base to somewhere that is on your path

Answer (score 2):

you nee to have an `__init__.py` file in each folder you import from

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a file called "`__init__.py`" at python directories, then "the Python" will understand that directory as a Python package.

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 things you can do:

add an `init.py` file to each folder

add `sys.path.append("Folder")` to the top

or use imp and do;

```
import imp
foo = imp.load_source('filename', 'File\Directory\filename.py')
```

then foo will be the name of the module for example `foo.method()`