# Not able to import custom modules in Python using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have created an python_util.py in the same folder where I have my Jupyter Notebook. Now on Jupyter notebook I want to import that as a module.

`from python_util import createLogging`

createLogging is a function inside python_util.py

I get the following error -

No module named python_util
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: No module named python_util

Can someone help me fix it ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us structure of your project files?

Comment: There is same problem with solution. This will help you to understand. visit reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976158/python-unable-to-import-module]

Answer (score 0):

You have added the local path to the path list.

```
import os
import sys
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('.'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```